# Why does sed only handle one file when receiving multiple files as input?

Tags: macos, sed

I have six CSV files I want to manipulate with sed

```
sed -i -e "1d" 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv 4.csv 5.csv 6.csv
```

or

```
sed -i -e "1d" *csv
```

but when running any of these commands only 1.csv is modified. However, sed renames the original of 2-6.csv (the timestamp of the backup file remain unchanged) to 2.csv-e and so on and create a new file 2.csv but this new file is identical to 2.csv-e (and diff:ing 2.csv and 2.csv-e returns no differences) (diffing 1.csv and 1.csv-e lists some changes).

How do I make sed accept more than one file as input?

This is on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

The [OSX `sed` man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) says

> Sed Addresses
>
> > An address is not required, but if specified must be a number (that **counts input lines cumulatively
> >          across input files**), a dollar (``$'') character that addresses the last line of input, or a context
> >          address (which consists of a regular expression preceded and followed by a delimiter).

So, you need a different approach

```
for file in 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv 4.csv 5.csv 6.csv; do
    sed -i -e "1d" "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your example but I am not sure I understand the quote from the man-page. What is an "address" and how is that relevant to my case? How is the $ sign relevant? My expression above works as expected, but only for one file at a time.

Comment: An example of an "address" in sed is the `1` in your sed program `1d`. In sed you can specify which lines you want a command to operate on with `N,M` (line numbers) or `/regex/`, etc. There are some online sed resources on [this site's sed info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info)

Comment: And yes, my answer only works on one file at a time because that's the way to solve your problem: you (apparently) want to delete the first line from several files.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU-sed, you can use -s:

```
 sed -i.bak -se  "1d" {1..6}.csv
```

(The {1..6} construct works at least in bash.)

The manpage of sed says:

```
   -s, --separate

          consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream.
```

and it works for me, including the in-place command and generation of .bak files. But I don't know for MacOS. Try with testdata first or read the man page.

Answer (score 3):

Glenn's answer is the best and ideal for most folk. There is an alternative with **GNU Parallel** that looks more like the command you were trying to come up with in your question, and runs 6 copies of `sed` (or anything else you fancy) in parallel:

```
parallel sed -i -e 1d ::: *.csv
```

Be very careful with it, as it can potentially modify very many things, extremely quickly in parallel. While you are getting acquainted with it, you should add two flags, namely `--dry-run` so that it does nothing and only shows you what it would do, and `-k` which keeps the output in order. So, the safer way to run is as follows - including being more selective on the files we process:

```
parallel --dry-run -k sed -i -e 1d ::: {1..6}.csv
```

**Output**

```
sed -i -e 1d 1.csv
sed -i -e 1d 2.csv
sed -i -e 1d 3.csv
sed -i -e 1d 4.csv
sed -i -e 1d 5.csv
sed -i -e 1d 6.csv
```

---

**GNU Parallel** is most easily installed on macOS with **homebrew**:

```
brew install parallel
```